# flutter: why two apk are installing instead of one

Tags: flutter, dart

i was working on my project and IDK what happened my project is one app but showing 2 icons, but only one is working and other one is not working how to solve this please any one can help me
this is my AndroidManifest code

```
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|
   screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|la 
      youtDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
        <!--fb login -->
 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
 android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" 
 android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
   <activity
    android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>

  <activity
  android:name=".MyActivity"
  android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
  >
  <meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
    android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
    />
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

and here code build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
 apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
android {
compileSdkVersion 33
flutter.compileSdkVersion
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
   kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
  }
   sourceSets {
     main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
   }
  defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
  (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.sample"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the- 
   build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion 21
    flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion 30
    flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
     release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
         }
      }
     }
    flutter {
    }
    dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.2')
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
    implementation 'com.zoho.salesiq:mobilisten:4.2.8'
    }
```

is it because of i migrated the app or something ? please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have multiple launchers, please choose only one Activity!

```xml
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```